# Backend can't get POST from javascript fetch API

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

No error appears (Would be good if appeared), and i've passed the whole day trying to make this code work. It's my first time with fetch using POST.
The thing is: the backend can't find any POST.
I will explain better after showing my scripts.

This is my front-end:

```
const corpo = {
    email: 'vila07@hotmail.com',
    password:'123',
}   
let url = "http://localhost/beauty/src/backend/login.php";
const options ={
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    header:{
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Accept':'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(corpo),
}

fetch(url,options)
.then((r)=>r.json())
.then((r)=>{
console.log(r);
});
```

I should be able to get email and password in my backend, but when I use:

```
if(!isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['password'])){
}
```

The code is triggered, because there is no email and no password in POST.

See my backend. I don't understand much about headers, wonder if the problem is in there. I used a standard one.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) { 
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"); 
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
}

$array = array();
if(isset($_POST['email']) || isset($_POST['password'])){
    $array = array(
        'email'=>'aa',
        'password'=>'bb'
    );
    echo json_encode($array);
}
else
{
    $array = array(
        'email'=>'No post found',
        'password'=>'No post found'
    );
    echo json_encode($array);   
}
?>
```

It is returning me this part of the code:

```
$array = array(
        'email'=>'No post found',
        'password'=>'No post found'
    );
```

Comment: Just tried without headers, the problem persists!

Comment: PHP doesn't parse JSON into `$_POST`. See the linked question for how to parse JSON body.

Comment: Put this in your PHP file to see the full POST data sent: $post = file_get_contents('php://input');

Comment: Thank you guys, it really helped me. So I could take the data this way:

$post = file_get_contents('php://input');
$post = json_decode($post);

$email = $post->{'email'};

Is there a problem taking the data this way? I Appreciate your help :D